# Jenkins Build Never Finishing

Tags: oracle, bash, jenkins

I have a Jenkins master/slave set up which has been working quite happily, running Oracle imports on some Linux boxes.

I have just added a new slave node and tried to run our existing database import job on this new node. This job consists of three subprojects; the first one runs some execute shells, copying files and changing permissions and this currently completes successfully, the second runs an execute shell which ends with an Oracle impdp. The impdp completes (the db exists and `ps -ef` no longer shows impdp running) but the Jenkins subproject never finishes. The UI just sits there with the clock whirring around.

I've tried adding an echo after the impdp, and this also executes correctly, but the subproject still never finishes.

If I add a Post-Build email notification, it is not sent.

The third subproject is never reached.

What could be the cause of this and how do I debug what is happening?

Comment: From your description I guess that some of the tools in your build is waiting for input - a yes/no prompt or similar. What happens if you run the build commands manually with the Jenkins account on the new slave?

Comment: That's the strange thing. The last command is an Oracle impdp and both when I run it on the slave manually, and when I view the console out in Jenkins I see "Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_03" successfully completed at Tue Jan 14 12:03:19 2014 elapsed 0 00:01:19". I can also add a plain 'echo "Job done" after that in the Execute Shell and that gets executed/echoed.

Comment: It's as if either, some other job/process/thing is being run after that point (but I don't know where that is configured or how to find it), or the Execute Shell needs some exit or return code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be something horrible :-)

After finishing the work, Jenkins tries to kill all processes it spawned. To identify them, it goes through all processes in the OS, reads from `/proc/<pid>/environ` (this is a Linux box) which contains the process’ environment variables and compares them with the environment it sets to Jenkins processes.

Problem was there was one particular Oracle process running on our db server where if you tried to read from `/proc/pid/environ` for it, it would just hang forever – which is where the Jenkins code would get stuck.

I have no idea why it was getting stuck like this and nor did our DBA. We restarted it and now it works.

Comment: How did you identify this particular process that Jenkins is trying to read?

Answer (score 5):

In our case, the jobs would declare "Finished: SUCCESS", but then continue with some unknown Jenkins business for another 10 or 20 minutes. After putting on more detailed logging, we found it was related to the ill-named LogRotator.

We have thousands of old builds and are deleting the artifacts for those older than a certain number of days. Because of the way old builds are handled, Jenkins searches the entire list of old builds even though they have already had their artifacts removed.

There is issue that is now fixed related to this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22607

As of right now I do not see it in a release, but if you have this issue, the temporary workaround is to turn off the deletion.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `set +x` to the top of shell scripts to see which commands are actually executed. That way you should be able to easily see from the output which command is blocking.

Comment: Thanks but I'm already using the +x, which is why I can see that whatever the last command is, within the execute shell, has run (impdp, echo...) I've now found out that I can even add a new Execute Shell build-step, after the existing one, and *that* will execute, but the sub-project as a whole is not finishing. This is very strange.